# How to put observe on a drop down and have it fire only when user makes a change

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've got several rows with each having its own drop down. When the dropdown is changed I would like to alert out the `ID` and the `value` selected from the drop down.

So I've added an `observes` on the property and it seems to work fine.

However, on the initial page load it alerts the `ID` and `value` of all the drop downs.

How can I make it stop alerting everything on the initial page load? Example here: http://jsbin.com/idevUCU/4#/posts/all

Comment: Are you triggering the event from a change on the `form`, `row` or `select` statement? It seems like your context is too high.

Comment: sorry, I just saw your comment in the other question, just add the prompt option to your select: {{view Ember.Select
        contentBinding= 'App.names.content'
        selectionBinding='selected'
        prompt="Select"}}

Comment: @user2506819 that works! if you want to add an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. just add the prompt option to your select:

```
{{view Ember.Select 
    contentBinding='App.names.content'
    selectionBinding='selected'
    prompt="Select"}}
```

you can replace "Select" with whatever you want.